# How to mock MVar2 make method

Tags: scala, cats-effect

I'm having trouble mocking the `MVar2` method `make` in my Unit test (using mockito).

I tried this:

```
private val sq = mock[MVar2[IO, String]]
```

and when I tried to mock the method like:

```
when(sq.take).thenReturn(
      "testString".pure[IO],
      IO.never
    )
```

I get the infinite loop in the test.

I was positive I could mock it like this.

The actual code calling the `make` is:

```
  def run: F[Unit] =
    fs2.Stream
      .repeatEval[F, String](signalQ.take)
      .map(encode)
      .unNone
      .evalTap(logMessage)
      .evalMap(send)
      .compile
      .drain
```

Comment: Mocking is a bad idea, you tie your code to the implementation rather than behavior. Just create this MVar and `put` there value before running `run`.

Comment: If you need to mock in order to test your code, then you probably have a design error somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues.

The first thing, there is no reason to mock IO. You can pretty much do this:

```
// define this wherever you create sq 
val sq = MVar2[IO, String]
// then DI sq and
sq.put("testString") >> run
```

Then the second thing, how does `.repeatEval(io)` works? It calls `io` repeatedly, every time the stream needs another element. So at first it would evaluate `io` with your mock to:

```
"testString".pure[IO]
```

which would compute the first element to `"testString"` and later to

```
IO.never
```

which means that the second element would never appear as this `io` would never return - neither value nor exception. And your stream halts as you can see. (Which would be according to the spec but apparently not what you want).

If you wanted to get `Some(string)` if value is present and `None` if it's absent (to terminate stream on `None`) you should try:

```
def run: F[Unit] =
  fs2.Stream
    .repeatEval[F, Option[String]](signalQ.tryTake)// <-- try to get None on empty
    .unNoneTerminate // <-- terminate on None
    .map(encode)
    .evalTap(logMessage)
    .evalMap(send)
    .compile
    .drain
```

Comment: 1. I want/need to mock MVar, due to it being an "outside" entity in my Program. 

2. The program works just as intended and as I want it to run. The things you wrote are the exact things I want to test. The program returns String and I don't want it to return anything else. So the second element should, not come. And for the terminate that is just not possible since this is real-time code, always running and just `unNone`ing and logging "wrong" cases and processing "right" ones. I still don't get why this doesn't work, when I have other working examples with IO.never and poll for example.

Comment: It doesn't work because IO.never never returns. Simple as that. You might have used it in combination with `racePair` or similar, where some other IO finishes earlier and `IO.never` is cancelled. Streams doing `eval` without `par` are baically guaranteed to perform operations in sequence - if one element is hanging, everything is.

Comment: I see, thank you, I gave you the correct answer.

Comment: NP, if you really need to have a prod stream that never ends and use it in test I would suggest rewriting the code to still enable shutdown with some `Signal` or something - even on prod it is useful to have an ability to perform a graceful shutdown.